# I Hope You Like Connect Walls! #5

Tags: word, connect-wall

As in previous puzzles, you need to sort the following 16 words into 4 groups of 4 words; each group will have something in common, and all the common things relate to a tag.

I've tried to make it harder to distinguish the possibilities, but there's still a tag that relates to everything.

> ```
>           ten     investigator     joker         spy
>
>           pets      seasons        thief        witch
>
>          mayor      militia        jack       nightlife
>
>          doctor      queen       vampires     werewolves
> ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Playing cards: ten, joker, queen, jack (found by Omega Krypton)
>  *The Sims* expansions: [Pets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sims_2:_Pets), [Seasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sims_2:_Seasons), [Nightlife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sims_2:_Nightlife), [Vampires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sims_4:_Vampires)
>  Roles in *[Mafia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mafia_(party_game))*: werewolves, investigator, doctor, mayor
>  Cards in *[Dominion](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Dominion_(Base_Set))*: spy, militia, thief, witch

So the missing tag is

> [game](/questions/tagged/game)

Comment: I'll allow it. I was expect roles in Town Of Salem instead of roles in Mafia, but they're pretty much the same game.

Answer (score 2):

Partial Answer

A

> ten, joker, queen, jack --> poker cards

B

> nightlife, werewolves, vampires, witch --> horror story elements

C

> investigator, thief, spy, mayor/ militia? --> detective story characters

D

> spy, doctor, mayor, militia --> people in military affairs

Tags

X

> [strategy] (used in both poker and military (assuming A and D are correct)

Hints from OP:

> 1 correct in A, B, and C

then

> 1 correct in A, B, C, D, X incorrect, implied: D incorrect

Comment: You have 1/4 groups correct.

Comment: Still only 1/4 groups correct. The tag is also incorrect.